# Android Studio 3.2 Beta 1 !zip.isFile Error

Tags: build.gradle, android-instant-run, android-studio-3.2

I've recently updated Android Studio and my build.gradle version to `3.2.0-beta01`.

When I build and run the project `!zip.isFile()` error occurs with information below:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: !zip.isFile()
>
> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
> ':app:transformDexWithInstantRunSlicesApkForDebug'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error vanished, after disabling Instant Run.

```
Android Studio -> Preferences -> Instant Run
```

Google has indicated that they are going to fix it in Beta-02

> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110564390